# What is the purpose of the Java static code block static {} in the given code?

Tags: spring-webflux, reactive

### in webflux,the code snippet is functioning correctly, but I don't understand the significance of the static code block within it.

```
@Configuration
public class WebGlobalResponseHandler {
    private static MethodParameter METHOD_PARAMETER;

    public WebGlobalResponseHandler() {
    }

    private static Mono<ResponseTemplete> methodForParams() {
        return Mono.empty();
    }

    @Bean
    public ResponseBodyResultHandler responseWrapper(ServerCodecConfigurer serverCodecConfigurer, RequestedContentTypeResolver requestedContentTypeResolver) {
        return new ResponseBodyResultHandler(this, serverCodecConfigurer.getWriters(), requestedContentTypeResolver) {
            public boolean supports(HandlerResult result) {
                return true;
            }

            public Mono<Void> handleResult(ServerWebExchange exchange, HandlerResult result) {
                Object returnValue = result.getReturnValue();
                Mono body;
                if (returnValue instanceof Mono) {
                    body = ((Mono)result.getReturnValue()).map((e) -> {
                        return new ResponseTemplete(e);
                    }).defaultIfEmpty(new ResponseTemplete());
                } else {
                    if (!(returnValue instanceof Flux)) {
                        throw new EventException(WebExceptionEnum.ES_WEB_002);
                    }

                    body = ((Flux)result.getReturnValue()).collectList().map((e) -> {
                        return new ResponseTemplete(e);
                    }).defaultIfEmpty(new ResponseTemplete());
                }

                return this.writeBody(body, WebGlobalResponseHandler.METHOD_PARAMETER, exchange);
            }
        };
    }

    static {
        try {
            METHOD_PARAMETER = new MethodParameter(WebGlobalResponseHandler.class.getDeclaredMethod("methodForParams"), -1);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException var1) {
            throw new EventException(WebExceptionEnum.ES_WEB_001);
        }
    }
}
```

### What is the significance of the static {} code block in the provided code?

```
static {
        try {
            METHOD_PARAMETER = new MethodParameter(WebGlobalResponseHandler.class.getDeclaredMethod("methodForParams"), -1);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException var1) {
            throw new EventException(WebExceptionEnum.ES_WEB_001);
        }
    }
```

I believe it is informing WebFlux that the intended return type is Mono.

Comment: The static code block is used to initialize the static variable with a bit of exception handling (rethrowing a different exception in this case) - is this all you wanted to know?